# svg image does not scale in table

Tags: html, css, svg

I am putting some svg images inside a table. But it is scaling down when the browser is resized. here is my code:

```
<div class="inner">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="middle"><a href="#"><svg.....</a></td>
            <td valign="middle"><a href="#"><svg.....</a></td>
            <td valign="middle"><a href="#"><svg.....</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.inner {
    width:100%;
    max-width:1400px
}
table {
    width:100%;
    max-width:1400px
}
a {
    display:block;
    width:100%
}
svg {
    width:100%
}
```

my page is totally responsive. when i try to scale down the browser, the svg images somehow does not scale to small size. it works in a div. and also it works only in chrome browser(with table).

the svg images are some .svg files. i have used them in img tag and used jquery function to make them show as svg resource.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are already doing it, since you didn't include the SVG element definition, but  you need to provide a viewbox attribute that indicates the area of the SVG you want to display.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox and http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute.

For example, try removing the viewbox attribute in the following fiddle to see the result without viewbox: http://bit.ly/1cZysAh

Answer (score 0):

What are the values of 'width', 'height' and 'viewBox' in your SVG files?  If they are a fixed pixel amount like "400px" or a physical amount like "2in", then your SVG will not scale.

If that is the case, set them to "100%" or remove them (which is equivalent because they default to 100%).

Also your CSS declaration setting 'svg { width: 100%}' is not doing what you think it is.  For instance, it is not the same as `<svg width="100%"...>`.

Comment: width="100%" should be the same as a CSS declaration for an outer svg element although the SVG specification says so it doesn't do so at all clearly.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I thought you couldn't override SVG attributes with CSS.

Comment: Almost, all rules have exceptions :-) and width and height on outer SVG elements are the **only** exceptions to that rule.